# How can we deselect the row when we Off the switch

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiswitch

I have a tableview. In the tableview cell I have a label and switch. Here I want to deselect the row when switch is off.

Here is my code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! BM_MyBusinessTableViewCell

    cell.tapSwitch.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.businessLabel.text = labelArray[indexPath.row]
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}
```

[image]

Comment: No rows are selected. There is nothing to deselect.

Comment: how can i select please suggest me@matt

Comment: can i use delegate

Comment: The row is selected when the user taps it. And then you are deselecting in the delegate. I don't understand what the problem is supposed to be.

Comment: when switch isOn = true the row should be normal but when switch isOn = false it should deselect the row... i trying this functionality... please help me @matt

Comment: i dont know how to write code for that..

Comment: I don't know what you mean by deselect the row. I can see from the screen shot that the row is not selected.

Comment: @matt i think what he is trying to say is that, he wants to disable the row if the switch is on. Meaning the user shouldn't be able to tap on the row/cell and interact with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't select/deselect the cell when the switch is tapped. Just store the indexPath.row of the selected switches and reload the tableview.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate   {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    let labelArray = ["Employees", "Break Time Setup", "Employee Timeoff", "Reports", "Messages"]
    var selectedIndexPaths = [Int]()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return labelArray.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! Cell
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        cell.tapSwitch.isOn = selectedIndexPaths.contains(indexPath.row)
        cell.tapSwitch.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.tapSwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tapSwitchAction(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
        cell.businessLabel.text = labelArray[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
    @objc func tapSwitchAction(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        if sender.isOn {
            selectedIndexPaths.append(sender.tag)
        } else {
            selectedIndexPaths.removeAll { $0 == sender.tag }
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Then you can get the selected row values anywhere like this

```
@objc func getSelectedValues() {
    let selectedLabelArray = labelArray.enumerated().filter { selectedIndexPaths.contains($0.offset) }
    print(selectedLabelArray)
}
```

**Update**

Option 1

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if selectedIndexPaths.contains(indexPath.row) {
        selectedIndexPaths.removeAll { $0 == indexPath.row }
    } else {
        selectedIndexPaths.append(indexPath.row)
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    //do nothing
}
```

Option 2

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? BM_MyBusinessTableViewCell {
        cell.tapSwitch.isOn = !cell.tapSwitch.isOn
        tapSwitchAction(cell.tapSwitch)
    }
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? BM_MyBusinessTableViewCell {
        cell.tapSwitch.isOn = !cell.tapSwitch.isOn
        tapSwitchAction(cell.tapSwitch)
    }
}
```

Comment: everything working fine but only thing is am unable to deselect is there any solution